# why does unregistering-reregistering MBeans make a difference with Jmx?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I'd like to register the MBean like this:

```
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName name = null;
    try {
        name = ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName();
        mbs.registerMBean(ApplicationTracker.getInstance(), name);
```

When I start the application, the registration fails and a javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException has been thrown, and I am not able to use the JMX functionality.

However everything works just fine, without any exception if I unregister-reregister the MBean like below. **Why?**

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName name = null;
        try {
            name = ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName();
            if(mbs.isRegistered(name)){
                mbs.unregisterMBean(name);
            }
            mbs.registerMBean(ApplicationTracker.getInstance(), name);
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is not run in parallel creating race when registering the MBean?
The "javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException" is thrown only when an MBean with the same object name already exists. 

BTW, what is the object name returned by ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName()?

Comment: The funny thing is if I just "swallow" the exception with a catch and carry on with the already registered ObjectName as if nothing happened then later I can't access the Jmx functionality. I need to unregister and reregister (with the very same object) and then everything works.  ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName() is a singleton, provides the same ObjectName object to all of its callers.

Comment: " ObjectNameProvider.getObjectName() is a singleton, provides the same ObjectName object to all of its callers." - does that mean that you would register more different instances under the same object name?

Comment: no, I use always the same object

Comment: I would start by adding a debug output (or setting a breakpoint) right before "mbs.isRegistered()" call to see that it your routine is called exactly once. Also, you can add Thread.dumpStack() to obtain the execution context.